# Table Row's onclick event should not affect only one Table data

Tags: html, css, jsp

I have a table in which all the rows are formed using a loop and all data are formed using a inner loop. I have a onclick event for all the rows and the destination will differ, according to the row that is clicked. I want this onclick event for the entire row except the first TableData. How to use a javascript function that will disable the onclick event only for the first the first TableData?

Comment: Hi Vee, please put a question in your question. Also some code so we can see what you have so far.

Comment: Hi Matt, I cannot show my code, since it is confidential.

Comment: Well you're going to have to come up with a short segment of code that illustrates your problem or this is a waste of time.

Comment: Change the confidential parts to dummy ones, we are not here to steal your work..

Comment: Just create an SSCCE. The *minimum* required code to reproduce the very same problem. http://sscce.org. You don't need to post the original code, it would only contain lot of unnecessary lines which are absolutely not related to the problem. JSP is also irrelevant here as it's just a template technology. Create a blank HTML page with the minimum required contents (a table) and create a Javascript function which is supposed to do its work but which didn't. Edit your question and post it. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jsp as well. Here is how:

just before your loop put a **counter** variable and equalize it to 0.
also before the loop put another variable called **isfirst**

now inside your loop, increment the counter var like counter++
after that run a condition like this:

```
if (counter == 1)
{
  isfirst = true;
}
```

Now where row is generated, put a condition that if it is first row, dont put the onclick event like this:

```
if (isfirst == true)
{
  // don't put onclick event for this row
}
else
{
  // put event for all other rows
}
```

**NOTE:** I don't know JSP, but you can mimic the code as shown above, thanks